# <atomic> not implemented while building a ROOT class

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, makefile, compiler-errors

I have been trying to `make` a ROOT Class called [RooUnfold](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/software/unfold/RooUnfold.html) which miserably fails while building with these errors:

```
Use ROOT 6.06/08 for macosx64 from /usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08
Making /Users/sudoankit/root/RooUnfold-master/libRooUnfold.rootmap
In file included from /Users/sudoankit/root/RooUnfold-master/tmp/macosx64/RooUnfoldMap_LinkDef.cxx:1:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08/include/root/TObject.h:31:
In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/root6/6.06.08/include/root/Rtypes.h:37:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/atomic:543:2: error:
      <atomic> is not implemented
#error <atomic> is not implemented
 ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [/Users/sudoankit/root/RooUnfold-master/libRooUnfold.rootmap] Error 1
```

How do I build it with `<atomic>` library?

Comment: What's your compiler including version and your compilation command?

Comment: Did you search for that error on the web? I see [this](https://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=18738), [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/217579/compile-error-atomic-is-not-implemented) and many more. The issue seems to be using an old compiler and standard library combo.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did but most of them have complicated solutions. One had to delete Xcode and every complier. 
I need to know how to edit the make file so to use g++.